# btrace didn't print out anything when the specified method is invoked

Tags: java, btrace

I'm learning how to use btrace. In order to do that, I created a spring-boot project which contained the following code.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/testFile")
    public Map<String, Object> testFile() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("/tmp/a");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        file.createNewFile();
        return ImmutableMap.of("success", true);
    }
}
```

Then I started the project using `mvn spring-boot:run`, after which I wrote a btrace script, as follows.

```
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.*;
import com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils;

@BTrace
public class HelloWorld {

    @OnMethod(clazz = "java.io.File", method = "createNewFile")
    public static void onNewFileCreated(String fileName) {
        BTraceUtils.println("New file is being created");
        BTraceUtils.println(fileName);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this script should print something when `java.io.File#createNewFile` is called, which is exactly what the above controller does. Then I attached btrace to the running spring-boot project using the following code.

```
btrace 30716 HelloWorld.java
```

30716 is the PID of the running spring-boot project. Then I tried accessing `http://localhost:8080/testFile`, and I got the following extra output from the running spring-boot project.

```
objc[30857]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10e2744c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1145e24e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2019-01-04 11:24:49.003  INFO 30857 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-01-04 11:24:49.003  INFO 30857 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-01-04 11:24:49.019  INFO 30857 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 16 ms
```

I was expecting it to output `New file is being created`, but it didn't. Why? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your trace method, `onNewFileCreated(String fileName)`, cannot be used to intercept `java.io.File.createNewFile()` as the signatures don't agree (`createNewFile()` doesn't take any arguments, while `onNewFileCreated()` has one).  If there are arguments in the trace method (unless they have a BTrace annotation), BTrace will attempt to "bind" them to the arguments in the intercepted method.  If it can't do so, it will not successfully intercept that method.

Try

```
@OnMethod(clazz = "java.io.File", method = "createNewFile")
public static void onNewFileCreated() {
    BTraceUtils.println("method createNewFile called");
}
```

or

```
@OnMethod(clazz = "java.io.File", method = "createNewFile")
public static void onNewFileCreated(@ProbeMethodName String methodName) {
    BTraceUtils.println("method " + methodName + " called");
}
```

**Update 1:**

First, what version of the JDK are you using?  BTrace doesn't appear to support JDK > 8 (https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/issues/292).

Second, can you try running this tracing script:

```
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.*;
import com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils;

@BTrace
public class TracingScript {
    @OnMethod(clazz = "java.io.File", method = "createNewFile")
    public static void onNewFileCreated(@ProbeMethodName String methodName) {
        BTraceUtils.println("method " + methodName + " called");
    }
}
```

against a simple test application:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        for(int i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
            File file = new File("C://Temp//file" + i);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }
            file.createNewFile();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me with BTrace 1.3.11.3 (and via the BTrace Workbench JVisualVM Plugin 0.6.8, which is where I usually use BTrace).

Comment: Thanks, I tried both of them, but still, none of them worked.